# Paypal with Single Page Apps in 2018

Tags: paypal, single-page-application

So, whats the current state of using paypal payments with a SPA? Is it still mandatory to use a new popup window, or is it possible now (in 2018) to do without, i.e. keep my user on my SPA / PWA all the time?

Comment: I don't believe at the moment this is possible in order to be PCI compliant while using Paypal.  You can get this using Stripe and if you can figure it out Square since they can be used to replace placeholder markup with their own elements.

Comment: I saw that Paypal also offers iframe integration. That could be a solution?